# Put text in different TextViews

Tags: android, string, textview

I am making an application on Android and I have a problem with EditText and TextViews. I have an EditText where an user puts his name, saved it with an "Ok" button and then the name is printed in 3 different TextViews.
For example, if there are 3 users A, B and C, the 1st textview will print "A", the second textview will print "B" and the third will print "C".

My problem is that if an user puts in the EditText "A", the three TextViews will print "A" and I want that if the first TextView is full, the name is saved in the second TextView and if the first and second TextViews are full, the text is saved in the third one.

My code :  **saveName.class**

```
            EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MemberInfo",
                    0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("Nom", nomrepete.getText().toString());

            editor.commit();
```

**printName.class**

```
TextView name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.savedname);
TextView name2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.savedname2);  
TextView name3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.savedname3);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MemberInfo", 0);
    name1.setText(settings.getString("Nom", "").toString());
    nomsauve2.setText(settings.getString("Nom", "").toString());
            nomsauve3.setText(settings.getString("Nom", "").toString());
```

I tried to put some conditions like if,
 `(name1.getText().toString() != " " && name2.getText().toString() != " ")` but without success.

Can you help me please ? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I realise I made some mistakes in the name of variables, I'm sorry...

I tried to do modifications on my code according to your solutions. The new code :

saveName.class

```
           EditText nomrepete = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nomrepete);
        nomrepete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MembreInfo",
                    0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("Nom1", nomrepete.getText().toString());

            editor.putString("Nom2", nomrepete.getText().toString());

            editor.putString("Nom3", nomrepete.getText().toString());

            editor.commit();
```

printName.class

```
    TextView nomsauve1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.savename);
    TextView nomsauve2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.savename2);
    TextView nomsauve3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.savename3);


    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MembreInfo", 0);

    if (nomsauve1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        nomsauve1.setText(settings.getString("Nom1", "").toString());
        System.out.println("user1");
    } 

    else if (!nomsauve1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        nomsauve2.setText(settings.getString("Nom2", "").toString());
        System.out.println("user2");
    }

    else if (!nomsauve1.getText().toString().equals("")
            && !nomsauve2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        nomsauve3.setText(settings.getString("Nom3", "").toString());
        System.out.println("user3");
    }
```

However, when I save a name, it is always saved in the first TextView "nomsauve1". If I put "if" instead of "else if", The 3 TextViews are full. I don't understant how the first condition can be respected whereas it is not empty ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use .`eqauls` to comapre strings

Comment: Instead of `name1.getText().toString() != " "` use `(!name1.getText().toString().equals(" "))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.equals` or `.equalsIgnoreCase` to compare strings

```
if (!name1.getText().toString().equals("") && !name2.getText().toString().eqauls(""))
```

Edit:

Also you are setting the same to all textviews

```
name1.setText(settings.getString("Nom", "").toString());
nomsauve2.setText(settings.getString("Nom", "").toString());
nomsauve3.setText(settings.getString("Nom", "").toString());
```

So change it to

```
name1.setText(settings.getString("Nom1", "").toString());
nomsauve2.setText(settings.getString("Nom2", "").toString());
nomsauve3.setText(settings.getString("Nom2", "").toString());
```

and you need to save the string from edittext

```
 editor.putString("Nom", nomrepete.getText().toString());
```

So what happens is values persist so you always get the new values in all the thre textviews

So you need to save with different key each time  like

```
 editor.putString("Nom1", nomrepete.getText().toString()); // Nom1 for first user
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare Strings only with `equals` or `compare` method.

```
name1.getText().toString().equals("")
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you have compared string with != operator ,that will not work as above answers show and they have suggested correct answer .

Second thing is that you have to create a logic for what you are trying to do means you are trying to split your text on those 3 textviews so if you will set

```
name1.setText(settings.getString("Nom", "").toString());
name2.setText(settings.getString("Nom", "").toString());
name3.setText(settings.getString("Nom", "").toString());
```

then definately they will print same out put so u have to create a logic for that when you want the text to be split to other text view like setting a fix length to textview or any thing else .